# How do I compile/open a flask project containing multiple python files

Tags: python-3.x, flask, compilation, project

recently a friend gave me a flask project to work on, when I opened the folder, there
were a multitude of files and folders and I was confused how to open the final website.
Can anyone please help me on how do I just load up the whole thing?
[image: Screenshot for reference, which file do I open?]

(NOTE: I already have python 3.7 and flask installed]